# How to update value X?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to use immutability-helper to update the object contained in my variable, the variable contains the following..

```
 {
  "_id": "XXXXX",
  "_rev": "XXXXX",
  "keys": {
    "component": "TEST",
    "type": "system"
  },
  "content": {
    "services": {
      "event": {
        "url": "https://example.net"
      },
      "copy": {
        "url": "https://example.net"
      },
      "humley": {
        "url": "https://example.net",
        "credentials": {
          "user": "TEST",
          "password": "TEST"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "processing": false,
      "syncTimeout": {
        "interval": 1,
        "intervalUnit": "minutes"
      },
      "products": {
        "hum": {
          "copySyncDate": "2017-01-21T13:20:12.633Z",
          "eventSyncDate": "",
          "workspaceSyncDate": ""
        }
      }
    },
    "syncTimeout": {
      "interval": 1,
      "intervalUnit": "minutes"
    }
  }
}
```

I am looking to update the values

```
"hum": {
              "copySyncDate": "2017-01-21T13:20:12.633Z",
              "eventSyncDate": "",
              "workspaceSyncDate": ""
```

I believe I can use the update function to update and store the new data in a new variable:

```
const documentUpdate = update(document, XXX);
```

But I can't work out what XXX needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
const documentUpdate = update(
  document,
  {
    content: {
      settings: {
        products: {
          hum: {
            $merge: {
              copySyncDate: 'value',
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
)
```

You could use `$set` instead of `$merge` if you want to replace the entire block.